# Help us become more active!

Tags: discussion

We've got a very nice community started here, and it's wonderful.

However, we have a very high proportion of people answering questions, and *not enough questions to answer*. We need more *experts*, or even just people with minor experience, asking questions instead of just waiting for them to come along and answering them (I'm guilty of this myself, to be fair).

So, consider this a call-to-action for people to ask questions. Ask away, share away, and if someone asks you a question that you think would apply here, ask away (or even get them to ask here).

You can also share your knowledge, by [self-answering your own questions](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)*!

<sub>* I may even throw in a bounty or two for a brilliant self-answered question.</sub>